# How to run Apache Flume 1.8 after building from Source?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I'm trying to build and run the Flume project from source, and the docs say that after running `mvn install` and extracting the `apache-flume-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz` in `flume-ng-dist/target`, that I should see an executable `apache-flume-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/bin/flume-ng`.  However, even though I see all of my compiled class files there, I don't see the executable.  The Maven build said it was successful.  Has something changed since the documentation was last updated?

https://cwiki.apache.org//confluence/display/FLUME/Getting+Started

---

I should have figured somebody would think I'd be dumb enough to not have Java or Maven installed.  Here's my enviornment.

```
/home/josiah/Development/apache/big-data/flume ➢ trunk± ✚ λ» java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

/home/josiah/Development/apache/big-data/flume ➢ trunk± ✚ λ» mvn --version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-78-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

/home/josiah/Development/apache/big-data/flume ➢ trunk± ✚ λ» protoc --version
libprotoc 3.3.0
```

---

Here's some of the Maven output (all of it would just be too much to post, here).

```
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (verify) @ flume-ng-dist ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ flume-ng-dist ---
[INFO] Installing /home/josiah/Development/apache/big-data/flume/flume-ng-dist/pom.xml to /home/josiah/.m2/repository/org/apache/flume/flume-ng-dist/1.8.0-SNAPSHOT/flume-ng-dist-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/josiah/Development/apache/big-data/flume/flume-ng-dist/target/apache-flume-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz to /home/josiah/.m2/repository/org/apache/flume/flume-ng-dist/1.8.0-SNAPSHOT/flume-ng-dist-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz
[INFO] Installing /home/josiah/Development/apache/big-data/flume/flume-ng-dist/target/apache-flume-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT-src.tar.gz to /home/josiah/.m2/repository/org/apache/flume/flume-ng-dist/1.8.0-SNAPSHOT/flume-ng-dist-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT-src.tar.gz

...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Flume checkstyle project ........................... SUCCESS [  1.268 s]
[INFO] Apache Flume ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.234 s]
[INFO] Flume NG SDK ....................................... SUCCESS [  3.868 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Configuration ............................. SUCCESS [  1.514 s]
[INFO] Flume Auth ......................................... SUCCESS [  3.272 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Core ...................................... SUCCESS [  8.966 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Sinks ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.186 s]
[INFO] Flume NG HDFS Sink ................................. SUCCESS [  2.451 s]
[INFO] Flume NG IRC Sink .................................. SUCCESS [  0.887 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Channels .................................. SUCCESS [  0.155 s]
[INFO] Flume NG JDBC channel .............................. SUCCESS [  1.779 s]
[INFO] Flume NG file-based channel ........................ SUCCESS [  3.979 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Spillable Memory channel .................. SUCCESS [  1.255 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Node ...................................... SUCCESS [  3.252 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Embedded Agent ............................ SUCCESS [  1.165 s]
[INFO] Flume NG HBase Sink ................................ SUCCESS [  2.708 s]
[INFO] Flume NG ElasticSearch Sink ........................ SUCCESS [  1.846 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Morphline Solr Sink ....................... SUCCESS [  3.293 s]
[INFO] Flume Shared Utils ................................. SUCCESS [  0.151 s]
[INFO] Flume Shared Kafka Test Utils ...................... SUCCESS [  0.670 s]
[INFO] Flume Kafka Sink ................................... SUCCESS [  1.251 s]
[INFO] Flume HTTP/S Sink .................................. SUCCESS [  1.612 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Kite Dataset Sink ......................... SUCCESS [  2.247 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Hive Sink ................................. SUCCESS [  1.918 s]
[INFO] Flume Sources ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.147 s]
[INFO] Flume Scribe Source ................................ SUCCESS [  1.173 s]
[INFO] Flume JMS Source ................................... SUCCESS [  1.803 s]
[INFO] Flume Twitter Source ............................... SUCCESS [  0.966 s]
[INFO] Flume Kafka Source ................................. SUCCESS [  1.902 s]
[INFO] Flume Taildir Source ............................... SUCCESS [  1.531 s]
[INFO] flume-kafka-channel ................................ SUCCESS [  1.468 s]
[INFO] Flume legacy Sources ............................... SUCCESS [  0.155 s]
[INFO] Flume legacy Avro source ........................... SUCCESS [  1.170 s]
[INFO] Flume legacy Thrift Source ......................... SUCCESS [  1.190 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Clients ................................... SUCCESS [  0.142 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Log4j Appender ............................ SUCCESS [  3.252 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Tools ..................................... SUCCESS [  1.024 s]
[INFO] Flume NG distribution .............................. SUCCESS [ 10.149 s]
[INFO] Flume NG Integration Tests ......................... SUCCESS [  1.158 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:18 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-21T20:34:35-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 556M/1005M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: you must have this tools to complete run the program  . Oracle Java JDK 1.7
Apache Maven 3.x

Comment: Of course.  Did you not see that I mentioned I ran Maven and the output indicated `mvn install` ran successfully?  My Java version is actually Java 8, though.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Deleting the local repository and re-cloning from GitHub solved the issue.  I'm still curious if anyone has any ideas as to why the build would succeed but then not produce the executables, though.